# Why do overhead maps for town not have front-looking icons for points of interest, like how overhead maps for landscape does?

Tags: maps

There are overhead generators for town maps, however the elements of interest (church, castle, etc) don't have an appealing looking. However in the case of overhead maps for landscapes, it seems that the elements (mountains, forest, desert, etc) have a more appealing depiction. They are not depicted as top-down, but as if the viewer is looking at them at the front.

[image]
<sub>Source: [Watabou's Procgen Arcana](https://watabou.github.io/)</sub>

I wonder why is that? And is there any generator that can produce a front-looking points of interest while the overall map is still overhead?

<sub>I'm also learning English, so would be appreciate if you can help me make this post sounds more natural to the natives</sub>

Comment: Maps are made in all sorts of ways. There's no way of knowing why a generator did what they did without asking the creator. Presumably they did what they did because it's similar to what other things that they see have done. I'm voting to close this question as opinion based as it's pretty unaswerable.

Comment: Do you find the answer below illustrate that this question is answerable?

Comment: No.............

Comment: can you explain why you don't think so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Different Purposes

One purpose for maps is to mark boundaries of properties. Boundaries might also be marked by boundary stones, but over decades something might happen to stones. So ancient civilizations developed the art of measuring properties from a nearby reference point. The Romans called this [centuriation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centuriation). There were limits on how far this could go before inaccuracies became inacceptable, so different cities had different reference points.

Maps of larger areas did not have the precision of these property maps. Mapmakers were aware of the problem, and many saw [mappa mundi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mappa_mundi) more like the [stylized charts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tube_map) of a subway system. For navigation, [books](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periplus) with descriptions were used.

There [were](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Magdeburg_1572_Franz_Hogenberg.jpg) city maps of the style you ask for, but care has to be taken so that landmarks don't obscure the roads.

### Accepted/Expected Iconography

There are different styles for modern topographical maps, including [hachure maps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hachure_map) and [shaded relief](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terrain_cartography#Shaded_relief). Doing them requires very good data and lengthy work, so shorthands developed to depict hills, mountains, swamps, etc.

Comment: so the reason we don't use it anymore is because of the requirement of precision that city maps need to have?

Comment: @Ooker, usually, with a city map, the goal is to display all houses and the roads to get there. What amounts to an oblique aerial photo with some landmark buildings enlarged would fail to do the job. The precision requirement also applies to maritime and aviation maps, so they don't show tourist information, either. By contrast, a [tourist map](https://i.dailymail.co.uk/1s/2019/09/07/11/18185344-7437965-image-m-2_1567851315120.jpg) does have landmarks obscuring roads. One might say that medieval people did not know enough about faraway countries that they would worry about a loss of detail.

Comment: Ah, tourist map is the one I'm looking for. Thanks.// Side question: why is this answer downvoted? For answering an off-topic question?